# Multiple column select for Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, html-select

I'm trying to find an open-source Angular library that will support multiple column selects. By that, I mean a library where the items will be arranged in multiple columns rather than each item having multiple columns (see image below).

I've found plenty of libraries that support tabular display of items but each item is still the entire row e.g. https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select.

Alternatively, does anyone have any suggestions on how this can be built?

[image: multiple column dropdown]

Answer (score 0):

Try with material of angular.io has components table: [Flex-layout tables with toggle-able sticky headers, footers, and columns](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-sticky-complex-flex)

Comment: But how would you put that into the dropdown part of a select?